# Add Margins to Background Image in CSS

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm trying to add fixed margins to a background image and having trouble. I want the image to take up roughly 70% of the screen width, positioned to the right centre of the screen and then to have equal margins on the top, bottom and right sides.

This is the code I have currently for my background image:

```
html, body {

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
background: url(http://japesfawcett.com/img/bg.jpg) no-repeat right center fixed; 
background-size: 70% auto;

}
```

I've put my full current code in a Pen, [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zRKXQy).

Here's an image that also helps to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to also consider adjusting `background-position`.

Here is an example with `30px` on top/right/bottom sides and image take **70%** of the width:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,white 30%,red 0);
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/107/800/800.jpg);
  background-size: calc(70% - 30px) calc(100% - 60px);
  background-position: right 30px top 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

You can also consider `background-clip` width padding or border:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,white 30%,red 0);
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  padding:30px 30px 30px 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/107/800/800.jpg);
  background-size: 70% 100%;
  background-position: right;
  background-clip:content-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I thought about this, but using background position doesn't allow me to have the 30% of white space on the left of the image which I'm trying to achieve. I'm wondering if placing the image in a separate div might work?

Comment: @Cavs28 yes you can use another div or pseudo element also ;) but am gonna think about a trick with only one div

Comment: @Cavs28 take a look to the update :) i found a solution